# Since timezone info is deprecated by numpy.datetime64 constructor, what's the right way to convert ISO 8601 datestrings?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a timeseries with a large number of ISO 8601 datestrings and would like to convert to `numpy.datetime64`. But I get a warning:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t=np.datetime64('2022-05-01T00:00:00-07:00')
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: parsing timezone aware datetimes is deprecated; this will raise an error in the future
```

**OK, so how do I avoid the warning?** (Without giving up a significant performance factor)

(Presumably the way to do this is convert to UTC and *then* create a `datetime64` object, but the whole point of using `datetime64` was that it worked directly on ISO 8601 strings very fast.)

[The documentation mentions this issue](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html) but doesn't suggest any solution:

> Deprecated since version 1.11.0: NumPy does not store timezone information. For backwards compatibility, datetime64 still parses timezone offsets, which it handles by converting to UTC±00:00 (Zulu time). This behaviour is deprecated and will raise an error in the future.

Comment: You can use Pandas: `t = pd.Timestamp('2022-05-01T00:00:00-07:00')`?

Comment: I suppose you have to pre-process the data to offset the times.  i.e. convert them to UTC before handing them to numpy.

Comment: bah, so I have to give up using numpy to do it quickly, so I can do it slowly

Comment: @Corralien -- I can use pandas, but it's > 10x slower than numpy's datetime64 constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ciso8601`](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601), a C ISO8601 parser:

```
# pip install ciso8601
import numpy as np
import ciso8601

dates = np.arange('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 1000000*60, 60, dtype='M8[m]')
dates = np.char.add(np.datetime_as_string(dates), '-07:00').tolist()
```

Performance:

```
>>> %timeit [ciso8601.parse_datetime(dt) for dt in dates]
73.9 ms ± 1.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit np.array(dates, dtype='datetime64[ns]')
457 ms ± 2.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, but it's significantly slower (I wouldn't care for < 10000 timestamps, but for millions or more, I'd like to maintain the fast time).

In Jupyter notebook:

```
import datetime 
import pandas as pd

def iso_to_datetime64_1(iso):
    return np.datetime64(iso)

def iso_to_datetime64_2(iso):
    return np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(iso)
                          .astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
                          .replace(tzinfo=None))

def iso_to_datetime64_3(iso):
    return pd.Timestamp(iso).to_datetime64()

test_time = '2022-05-01T00:00:00.123-07:00'
for f in [iso_to_datetime64_1, iso_to_datetime64_2, iso_to_datetime64_3]:
    print(f(test_time))
    %timeit f(test_time)
```

which prints out:

```
2022-05-01T07:00:00.123
574 ns ± 2.11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
2022-05-01T07:00:00.123000
3.32 µs ± 27.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2022-05-01T07:00:00.123000000
6.94 µs ± 44.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```